# randomly selecting percentage of ones from binary array row by row?

Tags: python, random, binary

I have an array of binaries ... what I want is to be able to pick a specific percentage of ones from every row ...
f.e. let say the number of ones are 100 per row, I want to get back randomly 20% from the first row, 10% from the second, 
40% 3rd, 30% from 4rd (total 100% of course).

```
0| 00000000001000000010000000000000000000001000000100000000000000000000000000000001 ... 
1| 00000000000000010000000000001000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000 ... 
2| 00000000000000000000000000000010010000000000000000000000000000010000100000000000 ... 
3| 01000000000000100000000000000000000000001000100000000000000010000000000000000000 ...
```

that is easy just do random.choice(one_idxs, %) on every row. The problem is that the **target** number of bits has to be 100 too ..
i.e. if some bits overlap and random selection picks them the total number will be different than 100 bits.

Plus on every row it should try to pick bits which were not selected previously at least as an option !

Any idea

---

Ex. code I use for the straightforward case, (which does not account if the selected indexes repeat across rows, just within a row) :

```
for every row :
   ones_count = 100
   bits_cnt = int(ones_count * probs[i])
   idxs = array.get_row(i).one_idxs()
   selected = np.random.choice(idxs, size=bits_cnt, replace=False)
```

---

I have to pick only the ONES .. thats why I'm using indexes

Comment: Inferring from your description, you want to avoid picking bits from the same index position in different rows?  (It isn't clear what you mean by overlap and not getting 100b above...)  So use 'random.sample()` to select 100 index positions and then for each draw, use a weighted distribution to select which row to pick from.

Answer (score 0):

Using lists of strings as a convenience instead of bit arrays and getting 4 samples...

```
In [39]: data = ['10000101', 
    ...:         '11110000', 
    ...:         '00011000']                                                    

In [40]: idxs = random.sample(range(len(data[0])), 4)                           

In [41]: # 20% row 1, 30% row 2, 50% row 3                                      

In [42]: row_selections = random.choices(range(len(data)), [0.2, 0.3, 0.5], k=len(idxs))                                                               

In [43]: idxs                                                                   
Out[43]: [7, 3, 1, 4]

In [44]: row_selections                                                         
Out[44]: [0, 2, 0, 1]

In [45]: picks = [ data[r][c] for (r, c) in zip(row_selections, idxs)]          

In [46]: picks                                                                  
Out[46]: ['1', '1', '0', '0']
```

Comment: i see so you create random 2D index .. and then pick the bits ... correct ?
btw i need to pick only ONEs

Answer (score 0):

OK, in light of your comment, this should work better as an example of how to pick ones only in proportion from each list/array:

```
import random
a1= '10001010111110001101010101'
a2= '00101010001011010010100010'
a1 = [int(t) for t in a1]
a2 = [int(t) for t in a2]
a1_one_locations= [idx for idx, v in enumerate(a1) if v==1]
a2_one_locations= [idx for idx, v in enumerate(a2) if v==1]

# lists of indices where 1 exists in each list...
print(a1_one_locations)
print(a2_one_locations)

n_samples = 6 # total desired

# 40% from a1, remainder from a2
a1_samples = int(n_samples * 0.4)
a2_samples = n_samples - a1_samples
a1_picks = random.sample(a1_one_locations, a1_samples)
a2_picks = random.sample(a2_one_locations, a2_samples)

# print results
print('indices from a1: ', a1_picks)
print('indices from a2: ', a2_picks)
```

Output:

```
[0, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 16, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25]
[2, 4, 6, 10, 12, 13, 15, 18, 20, 24]
indices from a1:  [6, 21]
indices from a2:  [10, 15, 4, 20]
```